# ESP_ATMod and its many library dependencies

Tags: esp8266

I'm trying to install https://github.com/JiriBilek/ESP_ATMod onto an ESP8266. The sketch has Includes to many libraries. Those libraries have includes to other libraries and so on. Do I have to manually follow all these dependencies and download them to compile and upload my sketch? Or is there an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Arduino sketch is a folder not a file. The ESP_ATMod sketch has 11 files:

```
asnDecode.cpp
asnDecode.h
command.cpp
command.h
debug.h
ESP_ATMod.h
ESP_ATMod.ino
settings.cpp
settings.h
WifiEvents.cpp
WifiEvents.h
```

The sketch doesn't include libraries which would require installation. It uses only libraries bundled with the esp8266 platform: EEPROM, ESP8266mDNS, ESP8266WiFi and LittleFS. You don't have to install any libraries.

You can download all the files at once with "Download ZIP":

[image]

Comment: Ah my mistake was not to set the board to ESP8266, it was still set to Arduino. The dependency error has now gone.